# Невалидная форма django

Tags: django

У меня есть форма, которую я хочу заполнять инпуты формы начальными данными взятыми с БД. Форма создается в модальном окне и заполняется данными используя js. 
Пример формы выглядит так:

```
<form action='{% url "change_employ" %}' method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}


<label for="name">Имя</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="name" >
<br>

<label for="last_name">Фамилия</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="last_name" >
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Изменить" />


</form>
```

Форма класс

```
class EmployForm(forms.Form):

name = forms.CharField()
last_name = forms.CharField()
```

Вью

```
def change_employ(request):
   if request.method =='POST':
       form = EmployForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
```

Поля заполняются, с этим все нормально. Передаю ее уже обычным способом через submit. Но во вьюхе метод формы is_valid() не проходит. И я не могу понять в чем именно проблема. Или форма пустая или причина в том что она создается не с стандартами django. В остальном, по полям она соответствует форме классу django.

Подскажите пожалуйста выход из этой ситуации. Возможно есть другая реализация такого функционала? Или можно в текущем варианте что то поправить? Спасибо

Comment: Ни у одного инпута нету атрибута name и форма получается пустая. И вообще читайте errors у формы, там всё написано

Comment: Вот же.. Провозился с ней кучу времени, а оказалось элементарное. Спасибо большое за помощь, добрый человек.